# How to remove the blue line from a Panel after creating a TitleBorder using BorderFactory?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, border

I created a JPanel and i have added a TitleBorder with BorderFactory but it's showing a blue line around the panel.
I would like to remove this line.

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: please show the code and printscreen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- never tried to extract this value from `TitleBorders AP`I, methods are protected, or by using `UIManager`
- have to use [LineBorder inside TitleBorder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/border/TitledBorder.html)
- simpliest syntax could be `xxx.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new LineBorder(Color.ORANGE, 1), "label"));` or get the `Color` from (for example) `myPanel.getBackground()` instread of `Color.ORANGE`
- another options are (is possible)

  1. move desciption (top, bottom.....)
  2. change `Font`
  3. change `Foreground` (`Color` for description)
- more options and description in Oracle tutorial [How to Use Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) (CompounBorders)

for example

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class AddComponentsAtRuntime {

    private JFrame f;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JCheckBox checkValidate, checkReValidate, checkRepaint, checkPack;

    public AddComponentsAtRuntime() {
        JButton b = new JButton();
        b.setBackground(Color.red);
        b.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 2));
        b.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 10));
        panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        panel.add(b);
        panel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new LineBorder(Color.ORANGE, 1),
                "Add Components At Runtime"));
        f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(panel, "Center");
        f.add(getCheckBoxPanel(), "South");
        f.setLocation(200, 200);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel getCheckBoxPanel() {
        checkValidate = new JCheckBox("validate");
        checkValidate.setSelected(false);
        checkReValidate = new JCheckBox("revalidate");
        checkReValidate.setSelected(false);
        checkRepaint = new JCheckBox("repaint");
        checkRepaint.setSelected(false);
        checkPack = new JCheckBox("pack");
        checkPack.setSelected(false);
        JButton addComp = new JButton("Add New One");
        addComp.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JButton b = new JButton();
                b.setBackground(Color.red);
                b.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 2));
                b.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 10));
                panel.add(b);
                makeChange();
                System.out.println(" Components Count after Adds :" + panel.getComponentCount());
            }
        });
        JButton removeComp = new JButton("Remove One");
        removeComp.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int count = panel.getComponentCount();
                if (count > 0) {
                    panel.remove(0);
                }
                makeChange();
                System.out.println(" Components Count after Removes :" + panel.getComponentCount());
            }
        });
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.add(checkValidate);
        panel2.add(checkReValidate);
        panel2.add(checkRepaint);
        panel2.add(checkPack);
        panel2.add(addComp);
        panel2.add(removeComp);
        return panel2;
    }

    private void makeChange() {
        if (checkValidate.isSelected()) {
            panel.validate();
        }
        if (checkReValidate.isSelected()) {
            panel.revalidate();
        }
        if (checkRepaint.isSelected()) {
            panel.repaint();
        }
        if (checkPack.isSelected()) {
            f.pack();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                AddComponentsAtRuntime makingChanges = new AddComponentsAtRuntime();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The *blue line* (in metal) is the default border used by TitledBorder if none is given explicitly. You need to provide another border if you don't like the default, f.i. an EmptyBorder:

```
myPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder
    (BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(), someTitle));
```